# How to send value of a button in laravel collectives?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

We can send the values of text as follows in laravel collectives? Is it possible to send the value of a button in laravel collecctives?

```
{{Form::text('element_id','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'value of a button'? Do you mean an `<input>` of `type` button's `value` attribute, or the html between `<button>` and `</button>`? Mayvbe have a look at: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#buttons?

Answer (score 0):

May the following will do the trick

```
{{ Form::button('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger delete', 'type' => 'button', 'value' => 'the value')) }}
```

Comment: I hope the solution is working for you. Or you should acknowledge the answer.